# Multiple random and increase value in a Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I would like to create with this code, to do a multiple random (ie a loop) to do a random 20-30 times. how could i do that? and I want to increase the value of the +1 textbox each time it goes to the next random step.

```
TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + 1
```

Code:

```
   Dim strWords As String() = str1.Split(",")
        'Create an instance of the Random class
        Dim ValRnd As Integer = TxtNumRnd.Text
        Dim rnd As New Random(ValRnd)' (Values Random not worked)
        'Get a random number from 1 to 80  (2 digits)
        TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + 1
        Dim randomNumber As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 81)
        If randomNumber = strWords(StrwrVal.Text) Then
            Exit For
        Else
            TxtRnd1.Text = TxtRnd1.Text & vbNewLine & randomNumber
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Values random not worked.

> Dim rnd As New Random(5)'

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do an what's not working. What is "not working" with `Dim rnd as New Random(ValRnd)`? Which part of that code provided should be looped? I'm assuming from `TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + 1` to the end should be in a loop? Are you expecting `Dim rnd As New Random(5)` to generate 5 random number? Just saying `not worked` doesn't help us understand the issue.

Comment: yes i expect to generate 5 random numbers. Dim rnd As New Random(5)

Comment: You are assigning a string value to an integer.  Replace `Dim ValRnd As Integer = TxtNumRnd.Text` with `Dim ValRnd As Integer = CInt (TxtNumRnd.Text.Trim ())`

Comment: That's not how random works. Calling `.Next()` is what actually generates the random number for you. Passing a value to the constructor such as `New Random(5)` is only setting the `seed` value that is used to calculate a starting value for your sequence of random numbers

Comment: @preciousbetine VB will do the conversion of string to integer for you. Visual Studio would actually tell you that the cast is redundant. Validating if the user input is an integer with `Integer.TryParse()` may be more beneficial

Comment: @LutfiMaulana you only answered one part of my first response. Your code snippet has two ending `Next` statements so this code already exists in a loop. I can't tell if those loops are all you need or if you need to add a loop into the code that you are showing. Can you update the question to include the full `For` statement.

Comment: So I understood, so how should I use the random procedure to generate more random numbers? exactly, this code already exists in a loop.

Comment: but the random procedure should work properly, generating multiple random numbers, not just one. Even if it were in a loop, each time it must generate a set of random random numbers.

Comment: If you are using the same seed value when you do [New Random(x)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8), and continue to initialize a New Random before you call `rnd.Next()`, you will always generate the same number

Comment: @Anu6is vb does not convert to an integer for you else there would be no such methods as `CInt()`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/implicit-and-explicit-conversions

Comment: See the [second example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: @Anu6is The above comment about Option Strict is not only meant for the OP but also for you.

Comment: I'm fully aware of the use of option strict. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this may not be a direct answer it should serve to clarify a few things.

The [Random Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Random__ctor_System_Int32_) - as I stated in the comments, using `New Random(5)` does not generate a sequence of 5 random numbers for you. It simply sets the seed for your random number generator. This means that the sequence of numbers that you generate when calling `Random.Next()` will follow the same pattern as they all have the same seed (see [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Random__ctor_System_Int32_)).

> Note: Ideally, when creating a `New Random()` **do not** set a seed value. They current time will be used as the default seed.

---

Creating a New Random(x) inside a loop with a defined seed

```vb
'Since random is declared inside the loop, using the same seed value 
'each time the loop executes, the same random sequence would be generated.
'Random.Next() will then continually access the first value in the sequence. 
For i = 1 To 5
    Dim rnd As New Random(5)
    TextBox1.AppendText($"{rnd.Next(0, 11)} | ")
Next
```

**Output: `3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3`**

---

Creating a New Random(x) outside of the loop with a defined seed

```vb
'Since random is now declared outside the loop, and Random.Next() is called
'inside the loop, the output sequence actually progresses.
'Note that the first number is the same as the previous example as the seed is the same. 
Dim rnd As New Random(5)
    For i = 0 To 5
    TextBox1.AppendText($"{rnd.Next(0, 11)} | ")
Next
```

**Output: `3 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 5 | 10`**

---

Creating **multiple** instances of New Random(x) **all with the SAME seed**

```vb
        'Instance 1
        Dim rnd1 As New Random(5)
        For i = 0 To 5
            TextBox1.AppendText($"{rnd1.Next(0, 11)} | ")
        Next

        'Instance 2
        Dim rnd2 As New Random(5)
        For i = 0 To 5
            TextBox2.AppendText($"{rnd2.Next(0, 11)} | ")
        Next

        Instance 3
        Dim rnd3 As New Random(5)
        For i = 0 To 5
            TextBox3.AppendText($"{rnd3.Next(0, 11)} | ")
        Next
```

**Instance 1 Output: `3 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 5 | 10`**
**Instance 2 Output: `3 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 5 | 10`**
**Instance 3 Output: `3 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 5 | 10`**

Comment: it was really helpful, exactly what I needed because I didn't understand certain things.