# Generate a sequence of 5 random numbers

Tags: vb.net

this code generates a single number, how could I generate more?

```
Dim randomNumber As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 81)
```

I would like to generate more random numbers using this code, but how could I do that?

Comment: Maybe start with a [For Loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement)?

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58462939/11159372) I thought you came to an understanding of using random numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple random and increase value in a Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461604/multiple-random-and-increase-value-in-a-textbox)

Comment: Yes start with a For Loop i think. I understood that random numbers, but it always generates the same numbers. it should generate differently each time.

Comment: Dim rnd As New Random(5)
    For i = 0 To 5
    TextBox1.AppendText($"{rnd.Next(0, 11)} | ")          - not worked. it generates the same set of numbers each time.
Next

Comment: You should not be using a seed at all when creating the `Random` object.  There's no point because it will simply use the current time if you provide no specific seed.  As has already been explained, if you use the same seed every time, the same sequence of numbers will be generated each time.  The only reason to use a seed is if you need to create multiple `Random` instances and, if you do that, you should start with the current time and then increment each time, so each seed is somewhat random but guaranteed to be different.

Comment: Also, I would tend to use `Enumerable.Range` for this, e.g. `Dim randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(Function(n) myRandom.Next(0, 81)).ToArray()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you generate your 5 random numbers, you need a place to store each number. I chose a List(Of T) because I don't have to know how many items I want to add in advance. You could also use an array.

When you instantiate the Random class without a seed then the class uses the system clock as the seed. This is the usual way to do it.

```
Private Sub OPCode(URL As String)
    Dim Rnd As New Random() 'No seed!
    Dim lst As New List(Of Integer)
    For i = 0 To 4
        lst.Add(Rnd.Next(0, 81))
    Next
    For Each i In lst
        TextBox1.Text &= i.ToString & vbCrLf
    Next
End Sub
```