# Dim shorting value x+1 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can I make this code shorter? that is, 10 random ones to be included in a loop.

```
Dim rnd As New Random()
Dim randomNumber1 As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 81)
Dim randomNumber2 As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 81)
Dim randomNumber3 As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 81)
Dim randomNumber4 As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 81)
Dim randomNumber5 As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 81)
Dim randomNumber6 As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 81)
Dim randomNumber7 As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 81)
Dim randomNumber8 As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 81)
Dim randomNumber9 As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 81)
Dim randomNumber10 As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 81)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a sequence of 5 random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58509096/generate-a-sequence-of-5-random-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array or a List. Here's how to do it with a list:

```
Dim randomNumberList As New List(Of Integer)

For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    randomNumberList.Add(Rnd.Next(0, 81))
Next
```

Have fun!